# Where is an accurate source for XLM to USD exchange rate?

Tags: transactions, xlm, exchanges

Where is an accurate source for XLM to USD exchange rate?
I'd like to programatically keep offers in line with market rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single source of truth for the price as every exchange has it's own.

- You may want to check [coinmarket.cap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/stellar/#markets) to have an overview what they scrape for their graphs and do the same. Or use their [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) but consider latency, availability and also that they have to weight/ filter their source data somehow.
- There is also 
  [stellar-price.com](http://stellar-price.com/#all-prices) as a community project with [open source code](https://github.com/andruby/pricey) and probably others.